# Could actions be a part of MVVM's ViewModel?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a viewModel written swift like this:

```
public protocol NewsViewModel {
    var imageString: String? { get }
    var title: String? { get }
    var dateString: String? { get }
    var action: (() -> ())? { get set}
}
```

Then my core data object is conformed to the viewModel as follows:

```
extension NewsDataObject {

    private func viewModel(action: (() -> ())?) -> NewsViewModel {

        struct NewsViewModelDefault: NewsViewModel {
            var imageString: String?
            var title: String?
            var dateString: String?
            var action: (() -> ())?
        }

        return NewsViewModelDefault(imageString: imgUrlString,
                                    title: articleTitle,
                                    dateString: pubDate,
                                    action: action)
    }
}
```

Is it good practice to use action inside the viewModel ? If yes or no, what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: view model is just a proxy to a model, so real question is: can action be part of the model?  I can imagine such scenario. So is this action have some impact on your business logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is really a judgement call based on what your action does. If your action simply updates the UI, it makes sense for it to remain in the controller or view. However if it is inherently integral with the model or network layer, it may make sense to move it into the view model.

Perhaps you could elaborate on your scenario here for better advice?

In general, I would always implement the initial control handler in the view or controller. And then call a method on the view model if needed.

```
/*
MyController
*/
myButton.add(target: self, action, #selector(buttonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)

func buttonHandler() {
    // Decide here if the actual logic belongs in the view model or controller
}
```

So catch the actions and pass the logic out to wherever makes most sense. At least that's how I would handle this.